# How to delete multiple added pointer of a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, delete-operator

I have a vector with some (among other classobjects) multiple added objects

```
class Foo {
  ...
  vector<Bar*> v;
  Bar* b = new Bar();
  v.push_back(b);
  v.push_back(b);
  ...
}
```

in Foo's destructor I do

```
for (vector<Bar*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    delete *it;
```

this causes an exception on the second iteration, because the object is already deallocated: "Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2."

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it by not using the terrible idea of storing raw pointers in a container. Instead, use a container of smart pointers:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

std::vector<FooPtr> v;

FooPtr b(new Bar());                 // #1

v.push_back(b);
v.push_back(b);
v.push_back(b);

// C++0x: even better method:
auto c = std::make_shared<Bar>();     // #2
v.push_back(c);
v.push_back(c);

v.push_back(std::make_shared<Bar>()); // #3

// Three distinct allocations of a Bar object have happened, #1, #2, and #3.

// No explicit deletions!
```

If you don't have C++0x, use the TR1 library:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```

(You don't have `make_shared` in that case, because that's a new gimmick using rvalue references and forwarding.)

Comment: `unique_ptr` is also a good idea if you don't need the reference counting overhead.

Comment: @Mike: Are you sure? How could you insert a unique pointer *twice* into a vector? I thought vector-insert would require move semantics, thus killing your original pointer.

Comment: My mistake. Missed the part where he's adding the same pointer twice.

Comment: @Mike: No worries. But if she didn't insert the same one twice, the original problem might never have shown up in the first place...

Comment: @Kerrek i am new to smart pointers. do you mean: FooPtr b(new Foo()); #instead of FooPtr b(new Bar()) it doesnt compile otherwise

Comment: @Derlange: `new Bar()` should work (I tested it, too), since `Bar*` is convertible to `Foo*`. You can treat the shared pointer like a raw pointer for all intents and purposes, only that you don't free any memory yourself (and you cannot assign new pointers directly, you have to use `.reset()`). What's your error?

Comment: @Kerrek well, in my case Bar doesn't derive from Foo, so it isn't convertible. But actually in my project this is the case, so your idea is working for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use a `shared_ptr`. You can find this in C++0x, TR1, or Boost. `shared_ptr` knows how many pointers still point to an object and only delete it when it's the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is due to the fact that you are allocating the memory only once in "Bar* b = new Bar()" and you are deleting it twice.You should allocate twice and then your code will not throw an exception.